# Estimate of higher order derivatives like $D^{\alpha}(|\xi|^k)$ and $D^{\alpha}(e^{-t|\xi| / 2})$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis

In Torchinsky's harmonic analysis book, proof of Theorem 5.1, he had the following estimate (5.7), but he didn't write down the proof of this step. I am confused because I think we're differentiating with respect to $\xi$, so the chain rule must be used and some $\xi_j$ components has to appear. Is he differentiating with respect to $|\xi|$ or $\xi$? Why is that estimate true? $\xi\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\alpha$'s are multi-indices. Any ideas will be appreciated. $m$ is a function satisfies H"ormander multiplier condition of order $k$, i.e.,
$$\sup_{R>0}R^{2|\alpha|-n}\int_{R<|\xi|<2R}|D^{\alpha}m(\xi)|^2\, d\xi<C$$ for any multi-index $|\alpha|<k$. Not sure if it helps.
[from the book:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGv40.png)

> In other words, it is bounded by expressions involving integrals of the form
> $$
> \int_{R^n}\left|D^\alpha\left(|\xi|^k e^{-t|\xi| / 2} m(\xi)\right)\right|^2 d \xi, \quad|\alpha|=k \tag{5.6}
> $$
> Let $\alpha=\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\alpha_3,\left|\alpha_1\right|+\left|\alpha_2\right|+\left|\alpha_3\right|=k$. Then the derivatives in (5.6) are linear combinations of monomials $D^{\alpha_1}(|\xi|^k) D^{\alpha_2}(e^{-t|\xi| / 2}) D^{\alpha_3} m(\xi)$ each of which can be dominated by
> $$
> c|\xi|^{k-\left|\alpha_1\right|} t^{|\alpha_2|} e^{-t|\xi| / 2}\left|D^{\alpha_3} m(\xi)\right| . \tag{5.7}
> $$

Comment: IMO Torchinsky has already written the proof. The paragraph between 5.6 and 5.7 is explaining the result of product rule. Derivatives are wrt coordinates of $\xi$

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thank you for the comment! But I didn't see why is the derivative bounded by the derivative wrt $|\xi|$, could you explain it a bit more?

Comment: Derivatives are wrt $\xi$. From which line to which line precisely?

Comment: @CalvinKhor Sorry I mean from (5.6) to (5.7). Since the derivative are wrt to $\xi$, so the chain rule must be used, but (5.7) is the derivative wrt to $|\xi|$. I didn't see why's the estimate true.

Comment: Why are you talking about chain rule, which is about composition of functions? This is the product of functions. You should use product rule i.e. Leibniz rule. And there are no derivatives wrt $|\xi|$ anywhere. Unless the part you are confused about is in bounding $D^{\alpha_1} (|\xi|^k)$?

Comment: @CalvinKhor Yes so I mean $|\xi|=((\xi_1)^2+\dots+(\xi_n)^2)^{1/2}$. So I'm confused why can he bound $D^{\alpha}(|\xi|^k)$ and $ D^{\alpha} (e^{-t|\xi|/2} )$ by $|\xi|^{k-|\alpha|}$ and $t^{|\alpha|} e^{-t|\xi|/2}$ respectively .

Comment: OK, i think I have written an answer that should help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> @CalvinKhor [...] So I'm confused why can he bound $D^\alpha(|\xi|^k)$ and $D^\alpha(e^{-t|\xi| / 2})$ by $|\xi|^{k-|\alpha|}$ and $t^{|\alpha|} e^{-t|\xi| / 2}$ respectively . - lzj 1 min ago

Lets say $f$ is $r$-homogeneous if $f(\lambda x) = \lambda^r f(x) $ for all $\lambda>0$. Then $D_if$ is $(r-1)$-homogeneous, where $D_i$ is the $i$th partial.

Proof:
$$ D_if(\lambda x) =\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x + he_i/\lambda )\lambda ^r - f(x)\lambda ^r}{h} = \lambda^{r-1}\lim_{\eta\to 0} \frac{f(x + \eta e_i ) - f(x)}{\eta} = \lambda^{r-1} D_if(x). $$

Immediate corollary:
$$ D^\alpha(|\xi|^k) \lesssim_{\alpha,k,n} |\xi|^{k- |\alpha|}.$$
Proof: $|\xi|^k$ is $k$-homogeneous. Induction with the previous result shows that $g(\xi)=D^\alpha(|\xi|^k)$ is $(k-|\alpha|)$-homogeneous. Hence
$$ g(\xi) = g\left(|\xi| \frac{\xi}{|\xi|}\right)=|\xi|^{k-|\alpha|} g\left( \frac{\xi}{|\xi|}\right)$$
and therefore $|g(\xi)| \le |\xi|^{k-|\alpha|}\sup _{\sigma: |\sigma|=1} |g(\sigma)|$.

With this in hand, the second result (...once corrected) is not so hard.

Claim: for $|\alpha|\ge 1$, $D^\alpha e^{-|x|} = P_\alpha(x) e^{-|x|} $ where $P_\alpha(x)$ is a sum of $r$-homogeneous terms for $r=0,-1,\dots,1-|\alpha|$.

Proof: $D_i e^{-|x|} = -(D_i|x|) e^{-|x|}  $ so the result is true for $|\alpha|=1$. Then induction proves the claim.

Since $D^\alpha (f(tx)) = t^{|\alpha|} (D^\alpha f)(tx)$ by chain rule, we see that the true result should be
$$ |D^\alpha e^{-t|x|/2}| \lesssim_{\alpha,n} t^{|\alpha|}\max(1,|t x|^{1-|\alpha|})e^{-t|x|/2} $$

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! But I'm still not able to to prove the second one, I worked in 2d case with $\alpha_2=(2,0)$. Then $D^{\alpha_2}(e^{-t|\xi|/2})=\frac{t^2}{4}e^{-t|\xi|/2}\frac{\xi_1^2}{|\xi|^2}-\frac{t}{2}e^{-t|\xi|/2}\frac{\xi_2^2}{|\xi|^3}$, it is not even bounded. Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: @lzj that's correct. I guess the final answer from your book isn't right then

Comment: @lzj I've done the second one, I think.

Comment: Thank you so much!! It has bothered me for couple of days. I think it works.